# Load data in a div after submit

Tags: forms

I've a form and when I click on submit button I call a mysql query. I want to show this query in a div of the same page because I don't want to refresh all the page. Only the div.
I do this with ajax without the form, getting the values of the inputs using js but the result of the query isn't exactly like a need (I'm using jquery datatables and not show the result as a datatable).
My question is if it's possible to send the data form to the div without ajax.

Comment: I think it can be done using JavaScript.

Comment: I think that but I don't know how to load the data of the query using javascript, because the where values of the query are in the form.